# Cocoa KVO:observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: is called twice for one value change

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, key-value-observing

I have a NSOperation subclass, which implements setFinished: to generate KVO notification:

```
-(void)setFinished:(BOOL)isFinished
{
    LogError(@"%@ will will changing isFinished to %d",self,isFinished);
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
    LogError(@"%@ did will changing isFinished to %d",self,isFinished);
    _isFinished = isFinished;
    LogError(@"%@ will did changing isFinished to %d",self,isFinished);
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
    LogError(@"%@ did did changing isFinished to %d",self,isFinished);
}
```

I am also sure that I have only add the observer to the operation once.

Strange thing comes, sometimes `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` for this object's `isFinished` key path is called twice, referring to the log, I only find `setFinished:` called once, and `addObserver:forKeyPath:` for this operation is only called once.

Also, I found that it's sequence is like this:

```
will will changing isFinished to 1
did will changing isFinished to 1
will did changing isFinished to 1
calling observeValueForKeyPath for object
did did changing isFinished to 1
calling observeValueForKeyPath for object
```

So anyone has any clue please?

Comment: The `iphone` tag implies iOS while the `cocoa` implies OSX. Which do you mean?

Comment: KVO is the same on both systems.

Comment: @rmaddy I just want my question to be exposed a little more, if I do run into some regulations, please notify me, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to take responsibility for calling `willChangeValueForKey:` and `didChangeValueForKey:`, you have to tell the system.  You can do that in two ways:

- You can override `+automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:` (a class method) on your class to return `NO` when the key is `finished`.  This is documented under [“Manual Change Notification” in the *Key-Value Observing Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002178-SW3).
- You can implement `+automaticallyNotifiesObserversOfFinished` to return `NO`.  This is documented in the `NSKeyValueObserving.h` header file, in the comment on `+automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:`.

If you don't implement one of these class methods properly, the system will automatically notify observers when `setFinished:` returns.  It looks like that's what you're seeing in your log.

Comment: To support the comment from the KVO header: The `automaticallyNotifiesObserversOf<key>` variant is properly documented in Leopard's [Foundation Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/Cocoa/FoundationOlder.html#KVCKVO).

Answer (score -1):

You need not implement 'setFinished:'.

The KVO method observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: is getting invoked once from setFinished: and again as you have explictly notifying the change using

[self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];

The solution would be to call [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"]; only when u set the variable 'finished'as follows:

```
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
self.finished = YES;
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
```

without overriding setFinished:

Comment: There is no need to call `willChangeValueForKey:` and `didChangeValueForKey:` there, because `self.finished = YES` sends the `setFinished:` message which, as you said, takes care of notification automatically.